# Using anchorString seems to break radio groups

Tags: docusignapi

If I specify a radio group using anchor strings, then when selecting one of the radio buttons, either the previous or next radio is marked as selected, not the one clicked.

```
"\"radioGroupTabs\": [
    {
    \"documentId\": \"1\",
    \"recipientID\": \"1\",
            \"groupName\": \"RadioGroup1\",
            \"radios\": [
                        {
                           \"pageNumber\": \"1\",
                           \"selected\": \"false\",
                           \"anchorString\": \"!!radio1\"
                        },
                        {
                            \"pageNumber\": \"1\",
                            \"selected\": \"false\",
                            \"anchorString\": \"!!radio2\"
                        }
                    ]
                }
]"
```

If I specify the position using x & y co-ordinates then it works....

Very confused here!

Comment: It's possible you've encountered an API bug, I'd reach out to your account manager to get this logged and fixed if that's the case.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the "value" node. When the expected behavior is to choose between the two, you should have a distinct value for each.

Example:

```
                        "radios": [
                            {
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "selected": "false",
                                "anchorString": "!!radio1",
                                "value": "Male"
                            },
                            {
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "selected": "false",
                                "anchorString": "!!radio2",
                                "value": "Female"
                            }
                        ]
```